# Start sidekiq bundler: command not found: sidekiq with mina - Spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, sidekiq, digital-ocean, mina

I have tried to deploy rails spree commerce project to ubuntu 14.04 server on digitalocean. Everything were well. But when I trying to deploy the project first time I get sidekiq error. I goggling something about that issue but I didn't get any solution.

after the

```
mina deploy
```

commad.

bundling and migrations work properly till the restarting of sidekiq.

The part of the deploying code which include the error is here:

```
-----> Launching
-----> Stop sidekiq
Skip stopping sidekiq (no pid file found)
-----> Start sidekiq
bundler: command not found: sidekiq
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
! ERROR: Deploy failed.
-----> Cleaning up build
Deleting release
Unlinking current
OK
```

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced same problem when I execute command 'mina deploy' after I update version of mina. My workaround for this problem is by modifying my gemfile to return to the older version of

'kgio' to version 2.9.2
'mina' to version 0.3.1
'mina-sidekiq' to version 0.3.0
'mina-unicorn' to version 0.0.3

After that, it works again like before